# How to reset Google Keyboard language using ADB?

Tags: adb, languages, gboard

So I have to add an automation step wherein the keyboard language needs to be reset in case someone changes it.

I have used `adb` for this and it works well on Samsung phones, but it doesn't work on Moto X and Nexus phones.

This is the `adb` command I use for Moto X and Nexus phones, but this doesn't have the desired effect.

```
adb shell pm clear com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
```

For Samsung phones, which is working, the command is

```
adb shell pm clear com.sec.android.inputmethod
```

Anyone can help? The only constraint is that I cannot root my phone.

Comment: @Firelord just this particular app mentioned `com.google.android.inputmethod.latin`.

Comment: or in other word, the keyboard is the stock Google Keyboard.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes you are correct.

Comment: @Firelord Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @AndrewT. have found the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that the command won't work for Google Keyboard because the selected languages are saved in the key `ENABLED_INPUT_METHODS` of the `Settings.Secure` table.

You can reset the selected languages of Google Keyboard with this command:

`adb shell settings put secure enabled_input_methods com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME`